# How do I insert data into a file using MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

Suppose I have a CSV file and I want to insert some data into that file. So how can I go about it?

Name,Address,City,State,ZIP
Jane Doe,123 Main St,Whereverville,CA,90210
John Doe,555 Broadway Ave,New York,NY,10010

For example, this is in my file but I'm not able to insert more data into this using MongoDB?

What I want is when I insert something in my collection it should update in the file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you want to do it using a programming language, through mongodb console or import the data as an excel datasource?

Comment: specify the programming language that you are using, mongodb insertion and the same data insertion on the files are different

Comment: I'm using elixir. I have only use postgres till now in phoenix but not mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to code this.

You can transform your JSON object to a CSV line, when trying to insert a document in your collection. and write the line in the csv file.

it's simple and straightforward if you are using something like python or nodejs.

Comment: I'm using phoenix for this but it's very complicated if I'm using phoenix